# Some Project in a solution is unable to find System references to NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, nuget

This is a project that's being cloned from Git, my references are all showing that it could not be found, even though some of it is built in system reference.  This solution was cloned from a Git Repository, and I have "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" checked. Furthermore, the path is Nuget.Config to all the packages is valid.

When I try to do "Restore Nuget Packages" on the solution, it says "All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.  There is no framework version issues either.

I have tried the following:

- Uninstalled Visual studio and reinstalling it.
- Clean solution, restore package and Rebuild the project
- Reinstalled all the Nuget packages by using update-package PackageName "" -reinstall

[Screenshot of Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGng.png)

Comment: Incompatible framework version maybe?

Comment: You could share a reproduce sample with us if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi zhouf, any update about this issue?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, the issue was resolved.  It turned out that although Nuget.Config's path is valid, the relative path in .csproj references are not.  After changing it, everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) First**, you should make sure that your VS has installed the related Net Framework SDK. If the git project targets to Net Framework 4.8, you should install the [Net Framework 4.8 Developr SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework) on your current PC.

**2) Second**, when you finish it, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the project.

**3) Third**, restart your project under then run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

**Update 1**

The issue is that the the `hintpath` of the nuget package from `csproj` file is not right. After changing the `hintpath` to the right ones under the PC, all works well.